# C# get fields with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

In C# how do you use reflection to get variables that doesn't have getters/setters? For example the getValue method below will work for d2, but not d1.

```
public class Foo {

    public String d1;
    public String d2 { get; set; }

    public object getValue(String propertyName){
        return this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: If they don't have getters or setters, they're not properties.  They're fields.  They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`d1` is not a property. It is a field. Use the reflection methods for Fields instead.

```
public class Foo {

    public String d1;
    public String d2 { get; set; }

    public object getValue(String propertyName){
        var member = this.GetType().GetMember(propertyName).Single();
        if (member is PropertyInfo)
        {
            return ((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(this, null);
        }
        else if (member is FieldInfo)
        {
            return ((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(this);
        }
        else throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdtchs6z.aspx) of `GetMember` you used doesn't return a collection, so the `Single` isn't necessary.

Comment: @vcsjones: Actually it returns an array (look at the link you provided), so it is necessary. It is possible to have multiple members (methods, specifically) with the same name. So although it breaks naming conventions, `GetMember` still has to return a collection.

Comment: Gha. I even linked to my own demise. Reading fail. I wrongly assumed it was the equivalent of `GetProperty` (which does NOT return an array) and `GetProperties` (which does).

Answer (score 5):

`d1` is not a property. It's a field. You would use `this.GetType().GetField` to retrieve it via reflection.

```
public object getFieldValue(String fieldName){
    return this.GetType().GetField(fieldName).GetValue(this);
}
```

What you are probably trying to is make getValue return the value of a property *or* field. You can use `GetMember` can tell you if it is a property or a field. For example:

```
public object getValue(String memberName) {
    var member = this.GetType().GetMember(memberName).Single();
    if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property) {
         return ((PropertyInfo)member).GetValue(this, null);
    }
    if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field) {
        return ((FieldInfo)member).GetValue(this);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Bad member type.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the GetField method.

[Msdn: Type.GetField()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfield%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)